# inequality based word problem.

Tags: inequality

$A$ can complete a piece of work in $16$ days and $B$ can complete in $x$ days. if $A$ and $B$ start working on alternate days, they together complete the work in same number of days irrespective of who starts working on the first day.

If this condition were to be satisfied, how many integer solutions of $x$ exist?